# your session has expired 2.3

Tags: magento2, php, session

Hello I am trying to install magento 2.3.5 p1 on my mac with mamp pro. My base url looks as follows

```
http://magmono:8888/
```

After I add a product to a card I get an error that session has expired. The popular solution to update url to 127.0.0.1 doesn't help. There is no such url

Comment: increase these values in you php.ini, memory_limit = 2048M and max_execution_time = 3600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by setting my base url to my ip address so now my magento url is

```
http://192.168.1.6
```

And this has solved the problem for me.